# How to measure UDP socket buffer loss on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, udp

Is there a way to view/measure UDP socket buffer loss on Windows Server 2008 R2? I've tried 'netstat -s' and looking at available perfmon counters, but nothing jumps out to me as a measure of socket buffer size or loss.

If there's no way to view it via some mechanism provided by Windows, I should note that the NIC in this server is an Intel Gigabit ET Dual Port Server Adapter. Perhaps there is some utility provided by Intel that can show this information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There may be a way to measure some types of loss, but in general, there's no way to know what you've lost.

Answer (score 1):

By "buffer loss", I assume that you mean losses caused by the buffer being full.  (UDP losses in the network can only be detected by designing a session level algorithm to track and confirm receipt of all packets.)

Outgoing buffer losses will be reported at the socket API level by error returns from [sendto()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or its equivalent) such as `WSAENOBUFS`, `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, or `WSAEMSGSIZE`.

As far as I know, incoming losses are not explicitly reported anywhere. However, you can use `ioctl(FIONREAD)` to determine how much data is in the incoming buffer.  If it is near full, and you are detecting losses, its a safe bet that those losses are the result of buffer overflow.